# How to calculate the number of multiplications happening in BatchNormalization layer during test evaluation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-complexity, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

or, why do my CNN's test evaluations take significantly longer with BatchNormalization than without?

I need to approximate the theoretical runtime for the evaluation of a trained CNN (using Keras with TF backend) on a test set. Thus, I attempted to calculate the number of mutliplications happening during evaluation to use this as a metric.

But for some reason, Batch Normalization (BN) appears to have a significant impact on the evaluation time, despite not being relevant in theory in my understanding.

I can calculate the number of multiplications for Dense and Conv Layers, and I thought I can ignore the computations for the activation function and the Batch Normalization as both only add one multiplication per Input, which is significantly less than what the Convolutional Layers do.

However, when I test the same network once with and once without Batch Normalization after every ConvLayer, I noticed that I cannot ignore it:
In the simple example given below, there only is one ConvLayer with filter size (3x3), followed by a softmax activated dense layer as I'm doing classification.
With BN after the conv layer, it takes me ~4.6 seconds to work through the test set.
Using the otherwise exact same net architecture without BN, the same test set is processed in half the time.

Summary of the test configuration with BN (finishes test set evaluation in ~4.6s):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 32768)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 43)                1409067   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,410,091
Trainable params: 1,410,027
Non-trainable params: 64
```

Without BN  (finishes test set evaluation in ~2.3s):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 32768)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 43)                1409067   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,409,963
Trainable params: 1,409,963
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I don't know how this scales as I don't understand the cause in the first place, but I can tell that I had tested other nets with 3 to 6 identical conv layers (using padding = same to keep the dimensions constant), and the difference in test evaluation appeared to vary between ~25% to ~50% in most cases (The one-conv-layer example given below even has ~100%).

Why does BN have such a big impact, in other words, what calculations  are happening that I'm missing?
I thought: BN just adds one multiplication per input. So, for example in the network with BN given above:
I expected batch_normalization_1 for example would add 32*32*32 multiplications, and conv2d_1 32*32*32*3*3 multiplications.

But then, how does that have so much impact on the overall runtime, even though the ConvLayers add more multiplications?

Code used to build the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(43, activation='softmax'))
```

with `x_train.shape[1:]` being `(32, 32, 3)`, representing a 32x32 image with RGB colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of answering my own question here, in case anyone stumbles across the same issue.

By embedding the Fritz AI benchmark libary https://docs.fritz.ai/python-library/benchmark.html, I could actually check the number of flops per layer, and it indeed turned out that the normalization only adds a neglectable amount of computations.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Layer (type)                                   Output Shape           MFLOPS     Weights       Core ML Compatible     
======================================================================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                              [None, 32, 32, 32]     0.92       896           True          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNormalization)     [None, 32, 32, 32]     0.07       128           True          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
flatten_1 (Flatten)                            [None, 32768]          0.00       0             True          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dense_1 (Dense)                                [None, 43]             2.82       1,409,067     True          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That said, the issue must be caused by some inefficent routine or even a bug in keras to evaluate models with Batch Normalization. Weird, but that is the only possible explanation.

Comment: Another possible explanation is that the fritz.ai flop count estimator is incorrect. I'm guessing its based off tensorflow's operation count tools which I have found to give gross errors when working out the actual FLOP counts for simple neural network architectures.